# Delete all post meta except featured image Using SQL

Tags: database, post-thumbnails, post-meta, mysql, phpmyadmin

Please I just migrated my site and I found out that wp_postmeta consumes most of my cpu resources, Is the any Sql code to Delete all post meta except the featured image. I dont want to Use wp functions for this. Just need only phpmyadmin sql code. I have read this similar [Post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/211518/delete-all-post-meta-except-featured-image), But I need the sql code for it, not functions

Comment: Are you *sure* you want to do this? There can be a lot of important stuff in meta.

Comment: Yes, I really want to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I rewrote the function from the link in your question to SQL.
Keep in mind that this script will also clear the page-templates assigned to the pages.

Make a backup of the `wp_postmeta` table first.

```
DELETE pm 
FROM wp_postmeta pm LEFT JOIN wp_posts p ON pm.post_id = p.id
WHERE
    (p.post_type IN ('post', 'page') AND pm.meta_key <> '_thumbnail_id')
    OR (p.post_type = 'attachment' AND pm.meta_key <> '_wp_attached_file' 
        AND pm.meta_key <> '_wp_attachment_metadata')
```